# Drop down custom field values do not work in multi-valued custom groups in profiles

Tags: custom-fields, profile, multiple-choice

We have a profile which exposes a custom group that allows multiple records. One of the fields is a drop-down list. In the profile, after clicking on Edit, you cannot see the drop-down list on the form - just the current value. When adding a new record, the drop-down list doesn't work either; nothing happens when you click on it. Is this intentional?
[image]

Comment: Any error on the console?

Comment: Maybe give it a try on the demo site (https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/) and see if you get the same result there?

Comment: 1. No error in the console.
2. The problem doesn't occur in the demo environment, but it does in our test and live 5.62.1 environments and my latest 5.64.alpha1 development environment. I wonder what configuration error we have?

Comment: Same extensions in all?

Comment: The extensions aren't the same. Is there an extension that could be the cause of the issue? 

I look at the source code of the two, and the 'offending' page seems to have some extra code. My knowledge of HTML is not enormous so it is hard to tell exactly what that means.

Comment: Can you add the extra code to your question?

Comment: And if you have the same extension in your dev, test and live, might be worth trying to disable it.

Comment: I disabled all the extensions in my development 5.64.alpha1 environment, but it made no difference - it still failed. Now looking again at the page codes. A preview of the profile field doesn't show the problem.

Comment: I noticed I hadn't got Form Builder and CiviCRM Administration UI,, but adding them didn't help.

Comment: This code appears between
... id="s2id_autogen1">
and
<select data-crm-custom...
<div class="select2-drop select2-display-none crm-container crm-public select2-with-searchbox">   <div class="select2-search">       <label for="s2id_autogen1_search" class="select2-offscreen">Skill</label>       <input type="text" ... spellcheck="false" class="select2-input" role="combobox" aria-expanded="true" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="select2-results-1" id="s2id_autogen1_search" placeholder="">   </div>   <ul class="select2-results" role="listbox" id="select2-results-1">   </ul></div>